# BSTS Model Co Efficients Change in different iterations in R

Tags: r, time-series, bsts

I have developed a time series model using BSTS package in R and set the seed to some constant value. When I rerun the model after few days using the same training data, the model coefficients are different than what I got the previous time. All the BSTS function parameters are exactly the same and the data is also exactly the same. Can someone tell me if any substantial changes were made the BSTS package recently or what could be the issue?